# Enabling CSS for elements from a specific file

Tags: html, css

I am developing a plugin for an application.
So lets assume that we have to css files,app.css and plugin.css

Content of app.css

```
.tempClass{
height : 50px;
width : 50px;
}
```

Content of plugin.css

```
.pluginTempClass .tempClass{
height : 40px;
}
```

Now if my plugin adds to the DOM of appliation a

```
<div class='pluginTempClass'>
     <div class='tempClass'>
         SOME CONTENT
    </div>
</div>
```

Here for height attribute the `.pluginTempClass .tempClass` selector has greater specificity so height rule for that gets applied but since this class doesnt define width, width rule of `.tempClass` of app.css gets applied.Is there anyway to avoid app.css styles being applied to plugin elements added to DOM

Comment: what mean plugin elements added to DOM? you want avoid with some tag?

Comment: means that my plugin adds elements like div to the application.In a way it inserts div tags.I just want to avoid styles from app.css to affect the elements the plugin adds

Comment: Patsy Issa:This will definitely work but only for this specific case.I may have other attributes as well.I cant go and manually set all attributes to auto.Thanks for answering though

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to set a new width in the plugin.css to also overwrite the value for width being used in app.css e.g.

```
.pluginTempClass .tempClass {
    height: 40px;
    width: xxx;
}
```

Where xxx is the width you want. To reset the width you would set it to 'auto'.

Comment: But this is for this specific case only.I want to generalise something to avoid this problem at all.I might have dozens of classes and attributes.Manually doing it isnt a good option I guess

Answer (score 0):

consider>

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style1.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style2.css">
```

if style2 is providing style for same element as style1, then style2's style spacification will override the style1's.

Comment: yup...but if style2 doesnt specify an style ,style1's styling will gain effect

Comment: Boss, suppose an element DOG. if you specify DOG's color is black in Style1.css and white in Style2.css then DOG will gain White color. 

But if you specify DOG's background-color is white in Style1.css and no specification of color in Style2.css then DOG will gain White background-color

Answer (score 0):

i suggest to add to the div or other tag inserted by the dom an attribute like

```
type="added"
```

in your css, you avoid this attribute

```
.tempClass:not([type='added']){
...
}
```

into this demo, try to delete the attribute type and css will be applied

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/r6Dd6/)